# Typo3 Call to a member function on null

Tags: dependency-injection, typo3

I have seen similar problems on Stackoverflow but none of those answers has worked for me (including clearing cache, clearing PHP opcode cache systems, de-activating and re-activating the extension). Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I am running a scheduled command for an extension. At some point my command will need to call the method test() from the MyController class.

I have tried to create a reference to the class via an inheritance call AND by ALL injection methods but no matter which way I try it I always get the same issue...:

```
Call to a member function test() on null
```

Most recently I used the injection method that is not recommended, but it simplifies my example below so I'll use it for now. (VendorName and ExtensionName are obvs dummy names):

```
* @var \VendorName\ExtensionName\Controller\MyController
* @inject
*/
protected $mc;  

public function myCommand()
{
     return $this->mc->test(); //should return true

}
```

...and inside MyController

```
public function test()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you flush system caches after changing your code? And it looks weird that you try to inject a whole controller. You should instead move the relevant code to a service or similar and use this in both locations.

Comment: Yes, all cached cleared inc the installation tootl php caches. 
All I want to do is call a function from another class. Extension builder tells me to use inject like displayed. Typo3 docs tell me there are 3 ways to use inject (all of which give the same error). Other people say not to use inject at all but make an instance of the class, which I've also tried , with the same issue. If you have a better way please let me know and I'll try it too.

Comment: In general the injection should be working, it's a bit hard to say what goes wrong without more code. If you just make an instance of the class in myCommand it's working I guess? (To make sure it's not an autoloading / class name issue).
What kind of Command is it and does it extend an extbase based command? Dependency injection will only work on classes instanciated via the object manager (meaning in extbase context).

Comment: What kind of object contains your "myCommand" function? The injection only works if your object is called by another Extbase object using ObjectManager->get()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't the injection call on the command Class, but some automatically generated code on the MyController Class. It seems Extension Builder can cause the error by incorrectly creating the @inject line in the wrong place. Here is the code it created automatically:

```
  /**
 * @var \VendorName\ExtensionKey\Domain\Repository\ExampleRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $importService = null;

 /**
 * @inject
 */

protected $exampleRepository = null;
```

...that second @inject call creates the error. It should be just:

```
 /**
 * @var \VendorName\ExtensionKey\Domain\Repository\ExampleRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $importService = null;
protected $exampleRepository = null;
```

Unfortunately the dubugging doesn't tell you which class is causing the issue so I naturally thought it was my own code.